# Why Overflow in MAX_VALUE in Int makes it negative but keeps it positive in Byte?

Tags: java

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int myMinIntValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int myMaxIntValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        System.out.println("The min Value Integer can hold is " + myMinIntValue);
        System.out.println("The Maximum Value Integer can hold is " + myMaxIntValue);
        System.out.println("The BUSTED MAX INT value is "+ (myMaxIntValue+1));
        System.out.println("The BUSTED Min INT value is "+ (myMinIntValue-1));
        System.out.print( "\n");


        byte myMinByteValue = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
        byte myMaxByteValue = Byte.MAX_VALUE;

        System.out.println("The min Value Byte can hold is " + myMinByteValue);
        System.out.println("The Maximum Value Byte can hold is " + myMaxByteValue);
        System.out.println("The BUSTED MAX Byte value is "+ (myMaxByteValue+1));
        System.out.println("The BUSTED Min Byte value is "+ (myMinByteValue-1));
        System.out.print( "\n");

    }
}
```

Returns

```
The min Value Integer can hold is -2147483648
The Maximum Value Integer can hold is 2147483647
The BUSTED MAX INT value is -2147483648
The BUSTED Min INT value is 2147483647

The min Value Byte can hold is -128
The Maximum Value Byte can hold is 127
The BUSTED MAX Byte value is 128
The BUSTED Min Byte value is -129

The min Value Short can hold is -32768
The Maximum Value Short can hold is 32767
The BUSTED MAX Short value is 32768
The BUSTED Min Short value is -32769
```

In the case of Int, The Maximum Value Integer can hold is 2147483647 when we add +1 ( Because of OVER flow it changes to negative, but in case of Byte if we add +1 it keeps adding? Someone explain why so?

Comment: Because `(myMaxByteValue+1)`, by default, result become `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add two numbers together, the operands undergo *binary numeric promotion*.

The operands are first unboxed, if necessary; then the first matching rule applies:

- If one operand is a double, the other is widened to double
- If one operand is a float, the other is widened to a float
- If one operand is a long, the other is widened to long
- Otherwise, both are widened to int.

Since `1` is an int (because it's an int literal), adding it to a byte means that the last rule applies, so the byte is widened to an int; and the result of the addition of two ints is an int.

Because 128 is within the range of int, no overflow occurs.

Note that the rules go no narrower than int, so even adding two bytes will result in an int:

```
System.out.println(Byte.MAX_VALUE + (byte) 1); // 128
```

Note also that if you used a pre/post-increment:

```
byte myMaxByteValue = Byte.MAX_VALUE;
++myMaxByteValue;
```

then the value of `maxByte` would be -128. This is because pre-increment is equivalent to:

```
myMaxByteValue = (byte) (myMaxByteValue + 1);
```

i.e. there is an implicit cast back to the variable type.

Answer (score 2):

If you add an `int` and a `byte`, the result will be an `int`.

When adding 2 integers types that are smaller(like `byte`s) than `int`, the calvulation will result in an `int`.

To resolve this problem, you can just cast the result to a `byte`:

```
(byte)(myMaxByteValue+1)
```